# Monitorar se serviços REST estão online

Tags: java, web-service, rest

Alguém sabe qual seria uma ferramenta interessante para monitorar se os serviços estão online ou não ?

Comment: Olá, Michel. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Poderia dar mais detalhes sobre os requisitos? A aplicação é sua? Tem uma URL que retorna o status? Se não, o que você considera suficiente para  dizer que ela está online? De onde você vai verificar isso (mesmo servidor, servidor diferente)?

Comment: obrigado @utluiz. Posso sim, trata-se de de vários serviços que retornam json e são consumidos por outros aplicações ou por apps. Considero estar ok o fato de existir conexão com a internet e existir o retorno dos dados. Quero ficar monitorando de um servidor diferente de onde está minha aplicação quer fornece os serviços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é o [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/). Ele permite você escrever testes do que se espera como resposta. Armazenar variáveis entre uma requisição e outra pra poder fazer fluxos de chamadas dentro de sua API. As rotinas de teste podem ser rodadas manualmente ou automatizadas segundo seus critérios.

Comment: Bem amigável e parece atender bem ao que preciso. Obrigado pela dica!! Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

O utilitário Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) representa um bom exemplo de ferramenta com funcionalidades que possibilitam o monitoramento de serviços. Disponibilizado gratuitamente pela empresa Telerik, este aplicativo pode também ser utilizado em verificações envolvendo Web sites. O aplicativo Fiddler conta com recursos que viabilizam ações como:

O debugging/depuração de requisições enviadas a uma aplicação (site ou serviço). Estas solicitações podem ter origens diversas, como dispositivos móveis e softwares instalados em sistemas convencionais como Windows, Mac e Linux;
A manipulação de sessões de usuário, com a alteração do conteúdo de requisições e respostas no padrão HTTP;
Testes de segurança e performance;
A customização das funções de monitoramento, a partir da implementação de extensões baseadas no .NET Framework.

[Leia mais em: Utilitário Fiddler: Monitoramento de Web Services](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilitario-fiddler-monitoramento-de-web-services/31274#ixzz44GIaxaDI)

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre ele. Você sabe me dizer se ele atende algo simples como, por exemplo, ficar monitorando o tempo todo se o serviço está ativo ou se o mesmo caiu ?